# "ERROR in Couldn't resolve resource from" for extensible angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I made a extensible parent component in Angular.

```js
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: '',
})
export class AbstractPagerComponent {...}
```

and get compilation error :

"ERROR in Couldn't resolve resource  from /this-path-is-ok/abstract-pager/abstract-pager.component.ts
"
I do not get what that error means because paths are ok and the component imported and added to a module.

Answer (score 3):

after a few my-head-bangs on the wall and a calls to Cthulhu, I realized that this means that he does not have a URL pattern in the component.

so I resolve it by change **templateUrl** to **template**

```js
@Component({
  selector: '',
  template: '',
})
export class AbstractPagerComponent{...}
```

Comment: You should remove @Component() from abstract class definition

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution related to this, create a new component from angular CLI within the same component folder( where you are getting errors), copy all of the logic, HTML code, and CSS files to this new component, and then delete the old component, now change the path and compile, hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the compiler could not find your `templateUrl`

As an example, for the following path

```
abstract-pager/
├── abstract-pager.component.html
└── abstract-pager.component.ts
```

the component would be

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pager',
    templateUrl: './abstract-pager.component.html'
})


export class AbstractPagerComponent{

}
```